# Which managed pipeline mode should I set for iisnode?

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

When using IISNode to serve a nodejs application on IIS, is it better to set the managed pipeline to classic or integrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely use either and disable ASP.NET if you don't use any ASP.NET. This mode only affects ASP.NET stuff.